# UISearchBar and UISearchDisplayController background color

Tags: ios, uisearchbar, uisearchdisplaycontroller, uisearchcontroller

I've added a `UISearchBar` into the navigation bar which it's visible when the user taps a certain button. Also, I've linked programmatically a `UISearchDisplayController`. The background color for the search bar is transparent.

My problem is that when the black semi-transparent overlay it's tapped and the `UISearchDisplayController` becomes inactive, I see a very ugly search bar animation: it stretches to full size (not showing cancel button anymore) and applying some kind o grey background.

When the user taps the cancel button in order to `UISearchDisplayController` become inactive everything it's fine.

Does anyone have a solution for my problem?

Thanks.

Comment: Add answer, any feedback is welcome.

Comment: The problem was the fact that I've added incorrectly the UISearchDisplayController reference to the left side menu centered view controller.

Comment: Then http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/96395/set-my-own-question-as-solved

Comment: take a look please at my previous answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/45555462/3472073

Answer (score 0):

You can make custom background images:

```
[searchBar setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"searchBarBackground"]];
[searchBar setScopeBarBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"searchBarBackground"]];
[searchBar setSearchFieldBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"searchFieldBackgroundImage"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

searchBarBackground

[image: searchBarBackground]

setSearchFieldBackgroundImage - transparent image
[image: setSearchFieldBackgroundImage]

Answer (score 0):

Because I was using *UIViewController+MMDrawerController.h* the correct way of setting *UISearchDisplayController* was:

```
[[UISearchDisplayController alloc] initWithSearchBar:search
                                  contentsController:self.mm_drawerController.centerViewController];
```