# How to change Background Color and Placeholder position of UISearchBar

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ios9, uisearchbar

[image]

I am trying to add UISearchBar on storyboard but i see there is not much option for Background color, text placeholder. Can i do that without programming ?

Comment: take a look please at my previous answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/45555462/3472073

Answer (score 1):

yes in attribute inspector you can find all the properties and make changes in your searchbar according to your need

[image]

OR

You can create a custom `UISearchBar` for your app

```
//Custom search bar code
    UISearchBar *search = [[UISearchBar alloc] init];
    search.frame = CGRectMake(0, 200, 300,45);
    search.delegate = self;
    search.showsBookmarkButton = NO;
    search.placeholder = @"Search/Select a Creative Service";
    search.barTintColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    [self.view addSubview:search];
```

Comment: abhinathan check once the qusetion , the questioner asked `Can i do that without programming `

Comment: yes in attribute inspector you can find all the properties and make changes in your searchbar according to your need