# UISearchBar background color not working with minimal searchBarStyle

Tags: ios, xcode, uitextfield, uisearchbar, ios13

I have a `UISearchBar` to which I want to set a white background.

Since I want to set a custom border, I choose the `minimal` value for `searchBarStyle`.

I can obtain a white background by setting `backgroundColor` and `borderStyle` to the `searchTextField` (this field is only available in iOS 13, to access it safely in other iOS versions check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58067550/3178759)), as follows:

```
searchBar.searchTextField.borderStyle = .none
searchBar.searchTextField.backgroundColor = .white
```

However, **this doesn't work in iOS 13**, it seems that the background color is ignored when `searchBarStyle` value is `minimal`, but correctly works for `default` / `prominent` styles.

Answer (score 3):

While trying to figure this out, I noticed that the background color was correctly applied when changing `searchBarStyle` at runtime using [Reveal](https://revealapp.com).

So I tried to toggle the `searchBarStyle in code after searchbar configuration and I managed to make it work!

```
func configureSearchBar() {

    // ... other searchbar customization code ....

    searchBar.searchTextField.borderStyle = .none
    searchBar.searchTextField.backgroundColor = .white

    if #available(iOS 13.0, *) {
        searchBarStyle = .prominent
        searchBarStyle = .minimal
    }
}}
```

I know this is a very fragile workaround but in my case it solved the problem.

Comment: This still works on iOS 15