# Swift - How to give shadow to UISearchBar but *not* its cancel button?

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, uisearchbar

I have a search bar that I have applied a drop shadow to, and as you can see [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e98q7.png), the cancel button casts its own shadow too. I would like for the shadow to be limited to the search text box. Here is what I'm starting with:

```
    let searchBar = UISearchBar()
    searchBar.placeholder = "KAT Milkshake"
    searchBar.backgroundImage = UIImage()
    searchBar.barTintColor = UIColor.white
    searchBar.compatibleSearchTextField.leftView?.tintColor = UIColor.gray
    searchBar.compatibleSearchTextField.backgroundColor = UIColor.white

    searchBar.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
    searchBar.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.25
    searchBar.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 2, height: 2)
    searchBar.layer.shadowRadius = 5
```

What I've tried:

1. I tried altering the cancel button's appearance via `UIBarButtonItem.appearance(whenContainedInInstancesOf: [UISearchBar.self])`, but it turns out that this object's shadow is a separate one. Notice the subtle [difference around the letters](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D3piN.png) after I applied another shadow by modifying the appearance shadow properties.
2. Giving the button a white image background didn't work, which I did by accessing `searchBar.value(forKey: "cancelButton") as! UIButton`. The shadow is applied [around the whole image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1QNRn.png) and looks even worse.
3. Adjusting the bounds of the search bar layer unfortunately did not work either (
   `searchBar.layer.frame = CGRect(x: searchBar.frame.minX, y: searchBar.frame.minY, width: searchBar.frame.width - cancelButton.frame.width, height: searchBar.frame.height)`).
   I gave the search bar layer a border to observe this, and the cancel button shadow
   [persists](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gyDvw.png).
4. I also tried unlinking the cancel button from the superview, but was only able to make it disappear entirely.

Is there any way around this? I'm on Swift 5 and iOS 14.

Comment: You can find UITextField of UISearchBar and customize it. You can search about extensions for accessing textField from searchBar.

Comment: @ibrahimyilmaz Wow, thank you! I feel silly for not thinking of this. It almost works - causes some unsightly clipping on the top and bottom shadows. I'll post an answer if I figure out how to fix it without reducing my shadow radius.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As ibrahimyilmaz suggested, adding the shadow to the UITextField instead of UISearchBar got the job done. Just had to modify my height and layout anchor constraints to handle clipping.

I followed [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58067550/7786888) by user Joshpy in order to access the text field. For iOS >= 13, making the shadow is as simple as:

```
    searchBar.searchTextField.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
    searchBar.searchTextField.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.25
    searchBar.searchTextField.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 2, height: 2)
    searchBar.searchTextField.layer.shadowRadius = 5
```