# swift i want to change search bar background colour white with black border

Tags: ios, swift

[here the screenshot that I want output please check](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HzClg.png)

I want the result like this search bar with background color white and black border
here my code is

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(true)
    
    for subView in searchBar.subviews  {
        if !subView.subviews.contains(where: { $0 as? UITextField != nil }) { continue }
        guard let textField = subView.subviews.first(where: { $0 as? UITextField != nil }) as? UITextField else { return }
        
        let placeholder = NSMutableAttributedString(
            string: "Search",
            attributes: [.font: UIFont(name: "Helvetica", size: 15.0)!,
                         .foregroundColor: UIColor.gray
            ])
        textField.attributedPlaceholder = placeholder
        textField.layer.cornerRadius = textField.frame.size.height / 2
        textField.layer.masksToBounds = true
        textField.textColor = .black
        textField.backgroundColor = .white
        
    }
```

[this is my output screenshot please check it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k9EAe.png)

I am unable to set search bar, please suggest me

Answer (score 1):

Good day! If I understand you correctly, then this may solve your problem. Extension for UISearchBar (Swift 5):

```
import UIKit

extension UISearchBar {

    func setupSearchBar(background: UIColor = .white, inputText: UIColor = .black, placeholderText: UIColor = .gray, image: UIColor = .black) {

        self.searchBarStyle = .minimal

        self.barStyle = .default

        // IOS 12 and lower:
        for view in self.subviews {

            for subview in view.subviews {
                if subview is UITextField {
                    if let textField: UITextField = subview as? UITextField {

                        // Background Color
                        textField.backgroundColor = background

                        //   Text Color
                        textField.textColor = inputText

                        //  Placeholder Color
                        textField.attributedPlaceholder = NSAttributedString(string: textField.placeholder ?? "", attributes: [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor : placeholderText])

                        //  Default Image Color
                        if let leftView = textField.leftView as? UIImageView {
                            leftView.image = leftView.image?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysTemplate)
                            leftView.tintColor = image
                        }

                        let backgroundView = textField.subviews.first
                        backgroundView?.backgroundColor = background
                        backgroundView?.layer.cornerRadius = 10.5
                        backgroundView?.layer.masksToBounds = true

                    }
                }
            }

        }

        // IOS 13 only:
        if let textField = self.value(forKey: "searchField") as? UITextField {

            // Background Color
            textField.backgroundColor = background

            //   Text Color
            textField.textColor = inputText

            //  Placeholder Color
            textField.attributedPlaceholder = NSAttributedString(string: textField.placeholder ?? "", attributes: [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor : placeholderText])

            //  Default Image Color
            if let leftView = textField.leftView as? UIImageView {
                leftView.image = leftView.image?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysTemplate)
                leftView.tintColor = image
            }

        }

    }

}
```

Also, you can try to do it with an image.
The way to do this only using Apple APIs is to create an image and use setSearchFieldBackgroundImage:

```
self.searchBar.setSearchFieldBackgroundImage(UIImage(named: "SearchFieldBackground"), for: UIControlState.normal)
```

Source: [Cannot change search bar background color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33751292/cannot-change-search-bar-background-color/52101495)

Comment: it shows me the error    // Type 'NSAttributedString' has no member 'Key'.                   on this line  -             textField.attributedPlaceholder = NSAttributedString(string: textField.placeholder ?? "", attributes: [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor : placeholderText])

Comment: Show your actual code, in context, where you try to use NSAttributedString.Key